# IDE python auto completion

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, emacs, autocomplete, wrapper

i have the following code:
(Please notice that the following code is a reduction of the real code)

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta


class MyFirstApi(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class A(MyFirstApi):
    def foo(self):
        print("A - foo")

class B(MyFirstApi):
    def foo(self):
        print("B - foo")


class MySecondApi(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

class C(MySecondApi):
    def bar(self):
        print("C - bar")

class D(MySecondApi):
    def bar(self):
        print("D - bar")

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, my_objects):
        self._my_objects = my_objects
        self._current_object_index = 0

    def get_current_object(self):
        return self._my_objects[self._current_object_index]

    def set_current_object_index(self, index):
        self._current_object_index = index

first_wrapper = Wrapper([A(), B()])
second_wrapper = Wrapper([C(), D()])
```

As you can see I have 2 APIs - the first defines foo function, the second defines bar function. A & B implements foo and C & D implements bar

Other than that I have wrapper class which gets list of objects, **The list can contain only 1 API implementation**, meaning it only gets A & B or C & D. It will never get A&C A&D B&C B&D.

The wrapper class implements "get_current_object" function which returns one of the implementations of that API

I'm using emacs(spacemacs) for python development (also tried vscode for my specific problem). The problem is that when i use "get_currect_object" I don't have correct auto completion

```
first_wrapper.get_current_object().foo()
second_wrapper.get_current_object().bar()
```

On that example my IDE won't complete foo or bar. I realize that the IDE has no possible way of knowing that is should complete foo or bar because the only way of doing so is running the code (which the IDE is not doing but parsing the module instead). I have also tried to override **dir** but IDEs aren't using that function, only ipython use it

Again, that code is a reduction of the real code. I realize that this code is a bit weird, the real code has better explanation of that code design, sadly i can't put it here because it is huge.

Is there any way to tell the IDE that the returned values can be foo or bar?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emacs with `anaconda-mode` and `company-anaconda` then you will get the completions you expect in your source buffer (once you have evaluated your code in the REPL).

[image]